# How to optimize $F=(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-y)^2+(c\sqrt{b^2-y^2}-x)^2, a,b,c>0$

Tags: optimization

$F=\left(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-y\right)^2+\left(c\sqrt{b^2-y^2}-x\right)^2,\quad a,b,c>0$

When $c=1$, we can optimize $F$ by using the substitution $x=a \sin(u), y=b \cos(v)$,
then $$F=a^2 \cos(u)^2+b^2 \cos(v)^2-2ab \cos(u)\cos(v)+b^2\sin(v)^2 +a^2\sin(y)^2-2ab \sin(v)\sin(u)$$
$$\implies F=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos (u-v).$$
So we get $$F_{min}=(a-b)^2, F_{max}=(a+b)^2. \quad (*)$$

What are other ways of getting (*) and how to do the optimization when $c\ne 1$ ?

Comment: You can use the same substitution to get $$F=a^2+b^2+(c^2-1)b^2\sin^2v-2ab(\cos u\cos v+c\sin u\sin v)$$ and take partial derivatives wrt $u,v$. Assuming none of $\sin v$, $\cos v$ or $\cos u$ are zero, we obtain the simultaneous equations $a\cos u=b\cos v$ and $\tan u=c\tan v$ which are readily solvable; for instance using $1+\tan^2=\sec^2$, we obtain $y=\pm\sqrt{(a^2-b^2c^2)/(1-c^2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your way of getting (*) is very nice.

For $c\not=1$, we have
$$\begin{align}F_{\text{min}}&=\begin{cases}(a-bc)^2&\text{if $\ \frac{a-bc}{1-c}\leqslant 0$}
\\\\0&\text{if $\ 0\lt\frac{a-bc}{1-c}\leqslant b$}
\\\\(a-b)^2&\text{if $\ b<\frac{a-bc}{1-c}$}\end{cases}
\\
\\\\F_{\text{max}}&=\begin{cases}(a+b)^2&\text{if $\ c<1$}
\\\\(a+bc)^2&\text{if $\ 1<c$}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

*Proof* :

Let
$$F(x,y):=\bigg(\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-y\bigg)^2+\bigg(c\sqrt{b^2-y^2}-x\bigg)^2$$
where $-a\leqslant x\leqslant a$ and $-b\leqslant y\leqslant b$.

For every $(X,Y)$ satisfying $X\geqslant 0$ and $Y\geqslant 0$, we have
$$F(X,Y)\leqslant F(-X,Y)\leqslant F(-X,-Y)$$
$$F(X,Y)\leqslant F(X,-Y)\leqslant F(-X,-Y)$$

So, from these, we can say the followings :

- To get the minimum, we only need to consider the case where $x\geqslant 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$.
- To get the maximum, we only need to consider the case where $x\leqslant 0$ and $y\leqslant 0$.

We have
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\bigg(xy-c\sqrt{b^2-y^2}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\bigg)$$

So, we get
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0\iff x=\pm x_0$$
where $$x_0:=\frac{ac\sqrt{b^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}}$$

**The minimum** :

For $0\leqslant x\leqslant a$, we have $F(x,y)\geqslant F(x_0,y)$.

Then, let
$$g(y):=F(x_0,y)=\bigg(\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}-a\bigg)^2\qquad (0\leqslant y\leqslant b)$$
We get
$$g'(y)=\underbrace{\frac{2(1-c^2)^2}{(\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}+a)\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}}}_{\text{positive}}\bigg(y^2-\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\bigg)y$$

Now, we have three cases to consider :

- If $\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\leqslant 0$, then since $y^2-\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\geqslant 0$, we have $g(y)\geqslant g(0)=(a-bc)^2$.
- If $\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\gt b^2$, then since $y^2-\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\leqslant 0$, we have $g(y)\geqslant g(b)=(a-b)^2$.
- If $0\lt \frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}\leqslant b^2$, then we have $g(y)\geqslant g\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2c^2}{1-c^2}}\bigg)=0$.

**The maximum** :

For $-a\leqslant x\leqslant 0$, we have $F(x,y)\leqslant F(-x_0,y)$.

Then, let
$$i(y):=F(-x_0,y)=\bigg(\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}+a\bigg)^2\qquad (-b\leqslant y\leqslant 0)$$
We get
$$i'(y)=\underbrace{\frac{2(\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}+a)}{\sqrt{y^2+c^2(b^2-y^2)}}}_{\text{positive}}(1-c^2)y$$

Now, we have two cases to consider :

- If $1-c^2\gt 0$, then we have $i(y)\leqslant i(-b)=(a+b)^2$.
- If $1-c^2\lt 0$, then we have $i(y)\leqslant i(0)=(a+bc)^2$.

Therefore, we get the conclusion written at the top.$\ \blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
F = \left(a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac xa\right)^2}-b\left(\frac yb\right)\right)^2+\left(c b\sqrt{1-\left(\frac yb\right)^2}-a\left(\frac xa\right)\right)^2
$$

now, as $|\frac xa|\le 1$ and $|\frac yb|\le 1$, calling $\frac xa = \cos u$ and $\frac yb = \cos v$ we have

$$
F = \left(a|\sin u|-b\cos v\right)^2 + \left(c b|\sin v|-a\cos u\right)^2
$$

etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts**: Use Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality instead.

We have
$$F = a^2 + b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2 
- 2y\cdot \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} - 2c\sqrt{b^2 - y^2}\cdot x.$$

(1) Maximum

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 F &\le a^2 + b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2
 + \sqrt{4y^2 + 4c^2(b^2-y^2)}\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2) + x^2}\\
 &= a^2 + b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2
 + 2a\sqrt{b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2}\\
 &= \left(a + \sqrt{b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2}\right)^2.
\end{align*}

(2) Minimum

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 F &\ge a^2 + b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2
 - \sqrt{4y^2 + 4c^2(b^2-y^2)}\sqrt{(a^2 - x^2) + x^2}\\
 &= a^2 + b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2
 - 2a\sqrt{b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2}\\
 &= \left(a - \sqrt{b^2c^2 + (1 - c^2)y^2}\right)^2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;u=\sqrt{a^2-x^2},\; v=\sqrt{b^2-y^2},\;$ then the given task about extremes of
$$F(x,y)=g(x,y,u,v)=(u-y)^2+(cv-x)^2,$$
gets the conditions
$$\begin{cases}
u^2+x^2=a^2\\
v^2+y^2=b^2.
\end{cases}$$
In accordance with the Lagrange multipliers method, the inner stationary points of the given task can be defined via the unconditional task of six unknowns in the form of
$$G(x,y,u,v,\lambda,\mu)=(u-y)^2+(cv-x)^2+\lambda (u^2+x^2-a^2)+\mu(v^2+y^2-b^2),$$
i.e. from the algebraic system
$$\begin{cases}
(x-cv)+\lambda x=0\\
(y-u)+\mu y=0\\
(u-y)+\lambda u=0\\
c(cv-x)+\mu v=0\\
u^2+x^2=a^2\\
v^2+y^2=b^2.\tag1
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
u(x-cv)+x(y-u)=0\\
v(y-u)+cy(x-cv)=0,
\end{cases}\quad
\begin{cases}
xy-cuv=0\\
cxy+(1-c^2)yv-uv=0,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
(1+c)xy+(1-c^2)yv-(1+c)uv=0\\
(1-c)xy-(1-c^2)yv+(1-c)uv=0\\
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
xy+(1-c)yv-uv=0\\
xy-(1+c)yv+uv=0\\
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
(x-cv)y=0\\
(y-u)v=0\\
\end{cases}$$
$$\left[\begin{align}
&cv=x,\qquad u=y,\qquad x^2+y^2=a^2,\quad x^2+c^2y^2=c^2b^2\\
&x=v=0,\quad y^2=b^2\\
&y=u=0,\quad x^2=a^2\\
&y=v=0,\quad 0=b^2,\\
\end{align}\right.$$
$$\left[\begin{align}
&x^2=\dfrac{c^2(b^2-a^2)}{c^2-1},\qquad y^2=\dfrac{c^2b^2-a^2}{c^2-1}\\
&x=0,\quad y^2=b^2\\
&y=0,\quad x^2=a^2.\\
\end{align}\right.\tag2$$

System $\,(2)\,$ defines the set of the inner stationary points. Also, the least and the greatest values of $\,F\,$ can be situated at the edges of the area.